# Url строка с массивом, php yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Делаю фильтр. Есть поля, где фильтр идет по массиву. В строке url генерируется вот такое обозначение массива `http://standart.dev/site/sell?city[]=87&city[]=88&city[]=89&course_type=1&price_type=1`

Где есть чекбоксы - вот так формирует `..city[]=87&city[]=88..`

Каким образом можна сделать url более seo-friendly? И вообще какие еще можна символы обозначения массива в url-строке использовать ??

Answer (score 0):

url более seo-friendly: `http://standart.dev/site/sell/city/87/88/89/cource/1/price/1/`

вопрос стоит только в том как вы будете этот урл обрабатывать.

Не рекомендую "СЕОшить" строки поиска с фильтрами. Передавайте параметры фильтров через POST, СЕОште только основные разделы, например `/sell/city/moscow/` =)

Comment: Вот такой url подходит, только бы массив как-то по другому сделать , на как я не пытался прописывать по другому в самой url строке - не понимает, что это массив `city[]=87&city[]=88&city[]=89&course_type=1&price_type=1`

Comment: Получайте не как массив, напишите свой роутер, в котором соберите свой массив http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html

Comment: Не, проблема в том, что в строку url нужно передать только значение, которые php примет за массив. Я конечно могу как-угодно url формировать, и через запятую, и через точку с запятой, но это не будеть принято за массив, и фильтр будет работать только для первого элемента.

Comment: К сожалению, только строка в виде: `?a[]=1&a[]=2` может быть воспринята как массив. Если это фильтры которые не нужно "СЕОшить" - передавайте их через POST, пользователям не всегда нужны ссылки на "строки поиска" им скорее нужны ссылки на конкретный "товар"